# Yii: how to show widget inside a TbTabs widget?

Tags: php, yii, widget, switch-statement

The Switch widget is not working when i check the page i get the following error. 
"Object of class WhSwitch could not be converted to string"

How can i get this to work for my script?

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
  'placement' => '',
    'tabs' => array(

    array('label' => Yii::t('strings', 'Settings'), 'content' => '
                <article class="settings-tab">
                <span class="settings-table">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Deadline of payment</td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control deadline-input"   placeholder="14"></td>
                      </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td>Link dropbox</td>
                    <td>
                    '.$this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.switch.WhSwitch', array('name' => 'switchbuttontest')).'                   
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td>Save to dropbox</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                     <td>Mail copy of invoice</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td>Get email when invoice is paid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td>Allow partial payments</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </span>
                </article>




                ', 'active' => true),
```

Comment: please see edits if they work

Answer (score 0):

try this,first save a widget in a variable like

```
$yourwidget=$this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.switch.WhSwitch',
 array('name' => 'switchbuttontest'));
```

now in your tbTabs widget put encodeLabel=>false like

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
  'placement' => '',
   'encodeLabel'=>false,
//your tabs
```

then use it like

```
<td>
.$yourwidget.                  
</td>
```

**EDIT:**
If above code does not work then there is more elegant solution to this.
Make a view file and put the whole code(which you want to show under tab) in that view file.In that file you can easily embed the widget between the elements without using quotation commas. and then you can use it like below

```
    array('label' =>Yii::t('strings', 'Settings'),
 'content' => $this->renderPartial('pages/_form_basic', true), 'active' => true),
```

Comment: I tried that but i still get the same error. but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

its fixed!

SOLUTION:

from 
'.$this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.switch.WhSwitch', array('name' => 'switchbuttontest')).'

to this

'.$this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.switch.WhSwitch', array('name' => 'switchbuttontest'), true).'